# Getting error 400 when submitting form to Google Forms in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, google-forms

I have a form on my website where the content will be saved to google forms. It worked earlier today, but suddenly I got an error (error code 400) when submitting. I don't know why this happens. It worked 1 hour ago. Haven't changed any code in the form as well. I deleted my responses between the last successful submit and the first error. Could this be the reason for the errors? Appreciate all help

```
const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        setSubmitted(true)
        setName('')
        setEmail('')
        setAge('')
    }

    const onIframeLoad = () => {
        if (submitted === true) {
            history.push("/bli-medlem")
        }
    }

<form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} method="POST" target="hidden_iframe" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18TBcc5oK0i0IEkMWJmRnljzaPSx8AjNR9Rseo8OkgKw">
                    <ul className="form">
                        <li className="form-element">
                            <label htmlFor="entry.2026036521">Namn</label>
                            <input
                                className="text-input"
                                name="entry.2026036521"
                                type="text"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element">
                            <label htmlFor="entry.2122300620">E-post</label>
                            <input
                                className="text-input"
                                name="entry.2122300620"
                                type="email"
                                value={email}
                                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                required={true}
                            />
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element dropdown">
                            <label htmlFor="entry.1689165674">Alder</label>
                            <select name="entry.1689165674" value={age} onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element">
                            <label htmlFor="training-choice">Vil du vera med på organiserte treningar i nokre av spela med tilbyr?</label>
                                <div className="choice"> 
                                <p>Ja</p>
                                    <input
                                        name="entry.737229839"
                                        type="radio"
                                        value="Ja"
                                        onChange={() => setValue("Ja")}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="choice">
                                <p>Nei</p>
                                    <input
                                        name="entry.737229839"
                                        type="radio"
                                        value="Nei"
                                        onChange={() => setValue("Nei")}
                                    />
                                    
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <label style={{fontSize: "24px", fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: '40px'}} htmlFor="entry.1182933035">Kva for nokre spel?</label>
                        <li className="form-element-choice">
                        <p>Fortnite</p>
                        <input
                            name="entry.1182933035"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="Fortnite"
                        />
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element-choice">
                            <p>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</p>
                        <input
                            name="entry.1182933035"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"
                        />
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element-choice">
                            <p>Rocket League</p>
                        <input
                            name="entry.1182933035"
                            type="checkbox"
                            value="Rocket League"
                        />
                        </li>
                        <li className="form-element">
                            <input className="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </li>
                        <iframe name="hidden_iframe" style={{display: "none"}} onLoad={onIframeLoad}></iframe>
                    </ul>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I set the state of every input field to `''` before the submit was finished. I removed

```
setName('')
setEmail('')
setAge('')
```

and the problem was solved.